# JQuery Validation with Select and Text Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm having one heck of a time getting this validation to work.

I'm using the JQuery Validation framework found [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), and I'm trying to validate a form that has both a select and an input as required fields.  I've managed to simplify the problem down to a rather simple prototype that demonstrates the problem:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ValidateTest._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" action="javascript:alert('hi!');">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
               <Services>
                   <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" />
                   <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" />
               </Services>
            </asp:ScriptManager>  
            <div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function() { 
                        $("#form1").validate();
                    });
                </script>   
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <select id="someselect" class="required">
                                <option></option>
                                <option value="value1">value1</option>
                                <option value="value2">value2</option>
                                <option value="value3">value3</option>
                            </select>         
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="someinput" type="text" class="required" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="somesubmit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The text box validation is being completely ignored on submit.  It seems that hitting the submit button only validates the select.

That being said, leaving the textbox blank will force the "This field is required" message to pop up, but when I hit submit, the form still submits.

What I'd like to see is obvious: both fields are required before submit.  That's it.  My guess is there's something really, really simple I'm just overlooking.

Comment: This SO Answer may help: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619816/jquery-validation-plugin-in-asp-net-web-forms/619950#619950>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `name` attributes on your form inputs. The Validation plugin ignores inputs (except `select`s, apparently) that don't have `name` attributes because they [don't get submitted anyway](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).

Just add name attributes to your inputs.

### Working Demo:

http://jsbin.com/idupe (editable via http://jsbin.com/idupe/edit#html)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
$("#submit").click(function() 
{    
      $("#form1").validate();                    
});
```

Comment: No dice.  That causes the form to submit every time.

Comment: shouldnt declaring the scripts be in the header not the body/form tag?

Comment: When I move the script into the header, I get an "Object Required" exception on loading the aspx page.  Hence my moving it to within the form, below the ScriptManager.

Comment: Looking at the demos they use " name " for each input, have you tried that?

Comment: Edit - somebody beat me to it :p