# How to check if .Net Validation is True before calling Click event

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using .Net validation to validate my form. The issue is when I click on Submit, it doesn't check if the form is validated or not. Even if the fields are blanks, it fires the alert. I want the alert to fire only after the form is validated. Thank you.

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" CssClass="error-box" />

<asp:Label ID="empLast4Lbl" runat="server" Text="Last 4 digits of SSN#">Last 4 digits of SSN</asp:Label>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="empLast4Txt"
                    ErrorMessage="Last 4 digits of SSN is required." ForeColor="Red" CssClass="float-none">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="empLast4Txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="empDobLbl" runat="server" Text="Label">Date of Birth</asp:Label>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="empDobTxt"
                    ErrorMessage="Date of Birth is required." ForeColor="Red" CssClass="float-none">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:TextBox ID="empDobTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="submitEmp" runat="server" Text="Submit" Class="ap-webmethod" />
```

// jQuery

```
$(".ap-webmethod").click(function () {

                alert("Fired");

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

it is achieved by Using jQuery Validation in ASP.NET Master Pages. see this link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=310

[jQuery Validation plugin in ASP.NET Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619816/jquery-validation-plugin-in-asp-net-web-forms)