# User Control Static Name Option?

Tags: asp.net, web-user-controls

I know there is a way to force asp web user controls (ascx) to use static ID's so they don't get appended with all the appended naming garbage...but is there way to do the same for the"name" attribute?  Specifically, in this case, for DDL's?  JQuery needs a specific name and I need to stop .NET from doing this.

Comment: Why not just have jQuery use the ID?

Comment: I'm using the Validation plugin and it requires/used "name".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/619950/284240

Comment: @JohnKinane: If the link answers your question you might upvote that answer and delete your question. This is not a duplicate since you've asked something else. Apart from that i don't know a way how to force ASP.NET to generate static names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not possible in ASP.Net for now ... I've found this combination to be an acceptable solution.

Add the `ClientIDMode="Static"` to the control:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Using JQuery, on document ready, set the name attribute on the control to the value of its id:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            // alert($("#HiddenField1").attr("name"));

            $("#HiddenField1").attr("name", "HiddenField1");

            // alert($("#HiddenField1").attr("name"));
        });
```

Comment: Hmmmm if we know that Id is HiddenField1 why should we select it again ? :)

Comment: BTW thanks for your answer. I used the same idea in one of my projects and that reminds me to up-vote your answer :)

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but would this not break any binding?  I know this would cause some issues in MVC.

Comment: @Christian Cody is right, for ASP.NET web forms it means the value of the control is not returned in the Viewstate, otherwise the solution works

Answer (score -3):

Try adding ClientIDMode="Static" to the control tag.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Comment: this makes the form's id as static but  not the name