# Jquery client validation asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am new to jquery ; i am using jquery validation as shown below:

```
    function validate() {
        return $('#aspnetForm').valid();
    }



<asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="false" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return validate();" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"></asp:Button>
```

**is this possible in asp.net ?;** 
currently this button is not post backing if function returns true

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Validation plugin in ASP.NET Web Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619816/jquery-validation-plugin-in-asp-net-web-forms)

Comment: i change java script to  function validate(e) {
            if ($('#aspnetForm').valid()) {

                __doPostBack($(e).attr("name"), "");
                return true; //proceed

            }

            else {
                  return false;  //cancel;
            }


        }  now its working

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery library, jQuery Validation plugin and meta plugin.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.5.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-multifile-plugin.googlecode.com/svn-history/r16/trunk/jquery.MetaData.js"></script>
```

---

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="{required:true, email:true,messages:{required:'required.',email: 'invalid email!' }}"></asp:TextBox>
    <!-- ... -->
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="submit" />
</form>
```

---

Use `validate()` of jQuery validation plugin on asp.net form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#form1").validate();
    });
</script>
```