# jQuery Validation plugin with a custom attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use the jQuery Validation plugin with this HTML:

```
<input data-validators="required" name="X2aasNr" type="text" value="Nedas" class="cleared" id="">
```

As you can see, I use a custom attribute named `data-validators`.  How can I use the jQuery Validation plugin for this case?

Comment: Since this has been marked off-topic for some reason I'll give a summary - create a global rule with `addMethod`. Then add it as a class to the input. If you need to specify data for the validation you can read custom data-attributes in the `addMethod` callback (it passes `value`, `element`)

Answer (score 15):

**Quote OP:**

```
<input data-validators="required" ...
```

> *"As you can see, I use a custom attribute named `data-validators`. How
>   can I use the jQuery Validation plugin for this case?"*

You can't.  [The plugin was not written to recognize that attribute](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/).

See:  http://jsfiddle.net/y5xUF/

However, you can define validation rules as per the following methods:

---

**1)  Declared within `.validate()`**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            fieldName: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTt2X/2/

**NOTE:**   If your field `name` contains special characters such as brackets or dots, [you *must* enclose the `name` in quotes](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference)...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            "field.Name[234]": {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

---

**2)  Declared by `class`:**

```
<input name="fieldName" class="required" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTt2X/1/

---

**3)  Declared by HTML5 validation attributes:**

```
<input name="fieldName" required="required" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTt2X/

---

**4)  Declared using [the `.rules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/):**

```
$('input[name="fieldName"]').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTt2X/3/

---

**5)  By assigning one or more rules to your own `class` using [the `.addClassRules()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules):**

```
$.validator.addClassRules("myClass", {
    required: true 
});
```

Then apply to your HTML:

```
<input name="fieldName" class="myClass" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uTt2X/4/

---

**6)  Declared by field type:**

```
<input name="fieldName" type="email" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gv0o6syt/