# jQuery Validation for all inputs of a given type

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to write a JavaScript function that would cover the validation of all the `input` elements of the `type="time"`. I am looking at the documentation of jQuery Validate but I'm only finding examples where the validation is bound on an `id` or `name` property. Is there a way to do this globally?

I want to make sure that a time is always of the format `hh:mm`. I have found a function that will validate my time (see below). When this function returns `false`, I would invoke an `addError()` function to add an error to the form. I'm not sure how to do this.

```
// Check is the input is a valid time
function formatTime(time) {
    var result = false, m;
    var re = /^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)\s*$/;
    if ((m = time.match(re))) {
        result = (m[1].length == 2 ? "" : "0") + m[1] + ":" + m[2];
    }
    return result;
}

// Trigger the validation on the onBlur event
$("input[type=time]").blur(function () {
    var value = formatTime($(this).val());
    if (value == false) {
        addError($(this));
    }
});
```

Edit1: It seems like my copy/paste skills aren't that good. In `formatTime()` I return the time if the format is valid and `false` if not.

Comment: You are not returning any value/result from `formatTime(time)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to [declare a custom validation method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to validate the time format.

```
$.validator.addMethod('correctTimeFormat', function (value, element) {
    var result = false, m, regex = /^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)\s*$/;

    if (m = value.match(regex)) {
        result = (m[1].length === 2 ? '' : '0') + m[1] + ':' + m[2];
    }

    return result;
}, 'Invalid time format.');
```

And then, require that custom validation method for all [input time](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.time.html) fields.

```
$('input[type="time"]').validate({
    rules: {
        value: { correctTimeFormat: true }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**Quote OP:**

> "I am looking at the documentation of jQuery Validate but I'm only
>   finding examples where the validation is bound on an `id` or `name`
>   property.  Is there a way to do this globally?"

Yes there is.  Rules can also be applied by using [the `.rules('add')` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules), and this method can be attached to any legal jQuery selector.  To use this method on more than one element, you must wrap it inside of [the jQuery `.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).  (Also note, even though you're not using the `name` attribute, each `input` must contain a unique `name`.)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({  // initialize the plugin on your form
        // any rules and/or options
    });

    $('input[type="time"]').each(function() {
        $(this).rules('add', {
            required: true,
            // another rule, etc.
        });
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/g8YFa/

[See this answer for complete info about adding rules using this plugin.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792569/594235)

Comment: may I know how you are adding second rules for another field? I have the first field text and the second field I have a mobile and third field I have email

Answer (score 0):

```
// Check is the input is a valid time
function formatTime(time) {
    var result = false, m;
    var re = /^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)\s*$/;
    if ((m = time.match(re))) {
        //Well it seems like its valid lets return true!  
        return true;
    }else{
       //Well it seems like this is invalid return false!  
        return false;
    } 
}
```

Comment: And how can I add this logic to all input elements of type="time"?

Comment: Well you could loop through them all, $('[type=time]').each(function(){formatTime($(this).val())}

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the value true/false from formatTime() function. So that it will set on your  "var value = formatTime($(this).val());" declaration!