# How to override your own jQuery's validate method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use jQuery validation method and I've set some default settings such as below

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorContainer : "#msgErrors ul",
    errorLabelContainer: "#msgErrors",
    wrapper: "li",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        lockScreen();
        if (typeof url !== 'undefined' && url != null) {
            loadContentViaAjax("tr#idElement", url, $(form).formSerialize(), "html");
        } else {
            form.submit();
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
        var divsMessages = $(".fadeOutAndEmpty");
        if (divsMessages.is(":animated")) {
            divsMessages.stop().removeAttr("style").show();
        }
    }
});
```

For these default settings work, I have to initialize the form by calling the validate method on every form that I have. To achieve this I placed after the page is fully loaded a call to

```
$("form").validate()
```

in an external JS file that is loaded by every page. This way all forms in my application will fire the validation method, but I didn't define any rules and calling validate method again passing the actual rules won't do the job.

Is there a way to define rules that has to be executed and those rules actually be executed even if the validate method has already been called?

Comment: How many forms do you have?  If it's a handful, then just call the validate method on each form, with the settings required.

Comment: Some of the forms does not have validations to be done at all, that's I placed an empty validate method. What I actually need is the code executed by the submitHandler. I think I'll bind this code in the submit event of each form and then call it in the submit handler.

Comment: [tag:jquery-validation-engine] is a totally different plugin.  I fixed your tags.  Please be more careful when tagging questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"The problem is that for this code to work I have to call the validate method in every form that I have."*

That's exactly what you are *supposed* to do, so I don't understand how or why this is a "problem".

**The `.validate()` method is how you *initialize* the plugin to work on a particular form.**  Not much different than how you would initialize any other jQuery plugin to target an element.

You can set the options within `.valdiate()` for the one targeted form, or you can set the options within `.setDefaults()` which will apply to all forms on the page.

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"I thought that by calling the method validate in my JSP, I would override the method, but it does not."*

Not sure what you mean by *"override the method"*, but `.validate()` can only be called *once* on a particular form.  Calling it again will do nothing.

---

**Quote OP:**

> *"The problem by doing that is I can't place any validation rules."*

Using the jQuery Validate plugin, rules can be declared on your form in many different ways.

Here are just two very simple examples....

---

**Example ONE - inline HTML by `class`**

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field" class="required" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // set defaults for all forms on this page
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        // your defaults
    });

    // initialize plugin on form with id #myform
    $('#myform').validate();

});
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/pMp6d/

---

**Example TWO - within `.validate()`**

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // set defaults for all forms on this page
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        // your defaults
    });

    // initialize plugin on form with id #myform
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        // other options specific to this form
    });

});
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/pMp6d/1/

---

---

**EDIT**:

If you need to declare rules *after* you've already called `.validate()`, you would use the `.rules('add')` method.

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/pMp6d/2/

```
$('input[name="fieldName"]').rules('add', {
    required: true
});
```

Alternatively, the same rule assigned to all `input` elements at once...

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});
```

---

**See this answer for more ways to declare rules:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792569/594235**

Comment: I'm aware of this two forms on how to validate forms using jquery's validation plugin, but unfortunatelly this does not answer my question. If I have a $("form").validate() I can't later have one specifying rules to override the first one.

Comment: @Philippe, your question, _"The problem by doing that [`$("form").validate()`] is I can't place any validation rules."_ ~  My answer shows that you can.  You're going to have to make your question more clear.

Comment: If I have a $("form").validate() I can't later have one specifying rules to override the first one such as $("form").validate({// do the magic here}).

Comment: @Philippe, no, you cannot override `.validate()` with another call to `.validate()`.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Now I can accept your answer. You just told me I can't do what I'm hoping to.

Comment: @Philippe, the `.rules('add')` method will allow you to declare rules at any time after `.validate()` is called.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and show how. And if were you that downvote the question, could you explain why?

Comment: @Philippe, there is a working demo for `.rules('add')` in my answer and also more written about the `.rules()` method in the answer linked at the bottom.  We generally do not discuss voting within comments, but it could have been because the question is not clearly written.

Comment: @Philippe, the down-voter may come back later and remove their vote if they see the question is edited/improved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42520/discussion-between-philippe-and-sparky)

Comment: @Daniel - you cannot dynamically change options.   There is no workaround.  Please do not ask new questions within comments section.