# jQuery Validation with multi-part form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

This will probably turn into multiple questions as I work my way through it but I'm in need of some serious jQuery help.  I've created a multi-part form based on the example at [bassistance.de](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/).  In that demo, the validation is fairly simple - designating required fields with a class, iterating through and pulling error messages from the form element title attributes.

My form is more complex than the demo - and I'm in over my head with implementing the validation in this instance.  For example, in the demo, the errors are coming right after the form element.  In my case, I want to designate the fields I want validate, create the rules and specify where I want to put errors with a class depending on whether they are errors or not.  I'm using the Blueprint CSS framework and it already has classes built for such things but, as I said, I can't figure out how to make that work.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to change the validation method in the demo as well and substitute one that I'm more familiar with - like:

```
$("#theForm").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if(element.attr("name") === "name") {
            error.appendTo("#nameError");
        }
    },
    groups: {
        capacityGroup: "progMin progMax",
    },
    rules: {
        fName: "required",
    },
    messages: {
        fName: "*First Name is required",
    }
});
```

So, I surely hope someone can help with this.  I've uploaded a slightly different demo at [www.43rdworld.com/multitest.htm](http://www.43rdworld.com/multitest.htm) with an added div for error messages and the stylesheet.   I'd really like to change the way the form is validated so that it will still validate from page to page before being submitted but let me specify the required fields, write my own rules and messages and specify where those messages will display.

Comment: Try to avoid linking to other sites holding source code and/or screenshots of your questions. The questions at StackOverflow should be self-contained and not subject to corruption if any of the external sites closes or changes its URL's.

Comment: Quote OP:  _"I'd really like to change the way the form is validated so that it will still validate from page to page before being submitted but let me specify the required fields, write my own rules and messages and specify where those messages will display."_  ~ Yes, you can specify all kinds of things but you have not properly defined what you want from us.

Comment: Demo at link above is a multi-part form built from an unordered list.  Uses buttons to go from 'page' to 'page' with a submit at the end.  The existing validation looks for a specific class as it iterates through that part of the form and places the error message adjacent to field. My requirements are more complicated and I need to specify my own rules, error placement and messaging but can't figure out how to validate each 'page' when I'm not really submitting the form until the end - I'm just toggling different sections to go from page to page.  Hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"**This will probably turn into multiple questions** as I work my way through it but I'm in need of some serious JQuery help."*

Your posting doesn't really fit the StackOverflow format where only concise and specific questions are expected.  Please see [the StackOverflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [sscce.org](http://sscce.org) for more posting guidance.

However, if you want to do a multi-step form with jQuery Validate, there are a few different approaches; here's mine...

---

When I create multi-step forms, I use a unique set of `<form>` tags for each section.  Then I use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid) to test the section before moving to the next.  *(Don't forget to first initialize the plugin; call `.validate()`, on all forms on DOM ready.)*

Then on the last section, I use `.serialize()` on each form and concatenate them into a data query string to be submitted.

Something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#form1').validate({ // initialize form 1
        // rules
    });

    $('#gotoStep2').on('click', function() { // go to step 2
        if ($('#form1').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 2 and hide step 1
        }
    });

    $('#form2').validate({ // initialize form 2
        // rules
    });

    $('#gotoStep3').on('click', function() { // go to step 3
        if ($('#form2').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 3 and hide step 2
        }
    });

    $('#form3').validate({ initialize form 3
        // rules,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
           // serialize and join data for all forms
           var data = $('#form1').serialize() + '&' + $('#form2').serialize() + '&' + $(form).serialize()
           // ajax submit
           return false; // block regular form submit action
        }
    });

    // there is no third click handler since the plugin takes care of this 
    // with the built-in submitHandler callback function on the last form.

});
```

Important to remember that my `click` handlers above are not using `type="submit"` buttons.  These are regular buttons, either *outside* of the `form` tags or `type="button"`.

Only the button on the very last form is a regular `type="submit"` button.  That is because I am leveraging the plugin's built-in `submitHandler` callback function on only the very last form.

**"Proof of Concept" DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/dNPFX/**

Also, see for reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546698/594235

---

**Quote OP:**

> "*I want to designate the fields I want validate, **create the rules and specify where I want to put errors with a class** depending on whether they are errors or not. I'm using the Blueprint CSS framework and it already has classes built for such things but, as I said, I can't figure out how to make that work."*

Again, that's not very specific.  Are you talking about using `class` to set the rules or using a custom `class` for error designation?  What have you tried? [The jQuery Validate plugin will allow you specify rules in many different ways including by `class`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792569/594235).

If you [refer to the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), you can see that there are options called `validClass` and `errorClass` that will allow you to specify different `class` names used for fields when they are valid or not.

Comment: Sparky - not an auspicious first post on my part and apologies to all for the multiple breaches of etiquette - I thought linking was okay as everyone seems to link to jsfiddle. That said, I'm trying to be as specific as my limited jquery experience allows and stay within 600 characters.  I was just explaining how the demo functioned as I understood it - relying on classes rather than rules.  That said, it looks like the example above is spot on - I was so determined to work with the existing code, I forgot about the click handler.  Thanks for your patience and I'll try to do better next time.