# jQuery Validation: Validate form in two parts

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to validate one form in two part, when I click the `btn` button then validation is done properly, but when I click `btnn` it's not working and always validates field1

This is my code

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            field1: "Please specify your name"

        }
    })

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            field2: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            field2: "Please specify your name"

        }
    })

    $('#btnn').click(function() {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
    Field 1: <input name="field1" type="text" />
     Field 2: <input name="field2" type="text" />
</form>

<div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate"/>
    <input id="btnn" type="button" value="Validate"/>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, you cannot call the `.validate()` method twice on the same form.  The `.validate()` method is used for initialization and the second instance will always be ignored.

You have two options here:

1. Put part 2 into its own `<form>` container.

OR

2. Some other trick like showing/hiding the form fields, or using the `.rules()` method to add/remove rules dynamically depending on which button is clicked.  If you're showing/hiding these fields, then declare all rules in the same instance of `.validate()` and leverage the default behavior of this plugin, which is to ignore all hidden fields.

Since you have not revealed the working concept of your multi-part form, or the purpose of wanting to validate in two parts, I will show you the simplest solution, which is suggestion #1.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form1").validate({ // initialize `form1`
        rules: {
            field1: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            field1: "Please specify your name"
        }
    });

    $('#btn').click(function() {
        $("#form1").valid();
    });

    $("#form2").validate({ // initialize `form2`
        rules: {
            field2: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            field2: "Please specify your name"
        }
    });

    $('#btnn').click(function() {
        $("#form2").valid();
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1"> 
    Field 1: <input name="field1" type="text" />
</form>

<form id="form2" name="form2">
    Field 2: <input name="field2" type="text" />
</form>

<div>
    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Validate"/>
    <input id="btnn" type="button" value="Validate"/>
</div>
```

Here is another answer showing how multi-step forms can be done:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20481497/594235

Comment: we cant do this with only one form ?

Comment: @Tarzan, Yes, the showing/hiding trick works on one form.  That's the point.   Move all rules into the same instance of `.validate()`

Comment: thanks sparky, i m using the second method, can we validate the hidden field according to steps i used the the ignore:[] but not work for me

Comment: @Tarzan, since I cannot see your attempts at solving this, I would have absolutely no idea where you went wrong.  *"not work for me"* is completely unhelpful.

Comment: No worry :) Thanks for every thing.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers do not mention a solution for validating a single form.
The accepted solution provides a workaround adding multiple forms.
Although an option does exist without adding  tags to your code.

1 - Store the validator object  by calling :
`let validator = $('#myform').validate({...});`

2 - Call the `validator.element('#myelement');` to validate a single element.
This way, you can validate multiple sets of element into a single form.

```
let validator = $('#myform').validate({...});
let numValid= 0;
 $('#myform .myfields').each( (i, el) =>{
    if ( validator.element( $(el) ) ) {
        numValid ++;                
        if ( numValid === fields.length ){
            // all fields are valids
        }
    } 
})
```