# jQuery validations using jQuery validate plugin in a separate js file in asp.net not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery validation plugin( latest version downloaded, added in my project) in asp.net project.
The problem is, my validation rules are in a separate js file. So when I type in `<%=textbox.UniqueID%>` I get an error - Expected identifier, string or number. I added quotes to make it a string - `"<%=textbox.UniqueID%>"` and now its just viewed as a string - it does not get the unique id of the text box.
But when I put these validations in .aspx page it's working fine but this is not I want, I want to put validations in separate js file

Here is what I have tried

filename: customscript.js

```
$("#form1").validate({

        rules: {
                <%= txtOtprId.UniqueID %>: //here I am getting error   Expected identifier, string or number
                {
                    required: true,
                    alphanumeric: true,
                    minlength: 12,
                    maxlength: 12
                },
                <%= txtName.UniqueID %>: //here i am getting error
                {
                    required: true,
                    lettersonly: true
                }
          }
      });
```

Comment: ASP code will not be evaluated in a JavaScript file, so whatever you put there will be treated as literal text.

Comment: The `<%= %>` items are meant to be replaced by the server when it renders the page. However, the server does not render .js files, nor would it know what `txtOtprId` is if that control is specified in another file.

Comment: Thanx, I got found an answer in below link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619816/jquery-validation-plugin-in-asp-net-web-forms
it would help somebody :)